# Failed to connect to port

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, apache-http-server, hosting

I have never hosted a website before, and I just tried to connect to my laptop's apache hosted site to the internet with my public IP, and then I found out that I need to disable the firewall, so I did that, and then I found out I need to use virtual server, so I set that up on my Dlink router like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/miPU9.jpg
and found out that I get this error: "Failed to connect to www.notaboutcelery.tk port 80: No route to host" can you tell me if I did the port forwarding wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Because your Dlink only forwards 8888 to 80... try again with www.notaboutcelery.tk:8888 or change your dlink settings to forward 80 to 80.

Comment: @Darius I tried both of those and I still get the same error

Comment: Try with your public ip? (Not your domain name just in case it has not yet set to revolve to your public IP). Also another you can test is your Apache server running (test by accessing localhost on your laptop)

Comment: @Darius do you mean when I visit the website, or I should put my public IP in the virtual server setup?

Comment: sorry I mean when you visit the website with a web browser.

Comment: Thank you, the public Ip worked, and now the domain works, it just took a few hours to change Ips.